# Mysql - How to select column where column name contains values from cell

Tags: mysql

Hello and thanks for taking the time to read this!

I have a table with columns labeled "WL1", "WL2", etc., up to "WL5".
"WL1" will always have a value, the other 4 columns may be NULL/empty/0.
All these columns are INT values between 0-15.

I also have columns labelled L1, L2, etc. through to L15.
These "L#" columns always contain TEXT/VARCHAR, for example "FORD", or "MERCURY"

Given the following:

```
W1 = 4
W2 = 12
W3 = NULL
W4 = NULL
W5 = NULL
L4 = 'TOYOTA'
L12 = 'SAAB'
```

The query should return the values of the "L#" columns where their column name contains the value in the "W#" columns - i.e. IF column WL1 = 4, return value of column L4, IF column WL2 = 12, return value of column L12, if WL3 = NULL, ignore, etc.

I found this from another answer here and hoped it would help get me started:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT( 'SELECT ',
        GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ',\n')
    )
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB_NAME' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE WL1;
```

Unfortunately this returns "Unknown column 'WL1' in 'where clause'" and I'm not even certain this is even close to what I want, but if it could have identified column names based on another cell's value, it would have been a start...

If this is something better done via PHP or another programming language, as opposed a mysql query, please advise - I'd be willing to explore that path, but would prefer the solution is done in sql if possible.

Any help resolving the error, or building a working query, would be appreciated!

Comment: The real problem is that your schema is really bad. You have encoded values into your database columns. This would be a cakewalk if you stored a separate row for each `W` key/value pair and a separate `L` key/value pair. Now you are stuck dynamically determining which database object (a column in this case) should be used in your SQL dynamically at run time which isn't going to happen in pure sql. Is it possible to change your schema at this point?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this only with SQL. I would use a script language like Python, query the whole table and then loop trough the results to get the inormation you need in another query

Comment: Either dynamic SQL or complex CASE.

Comment: A complex `CASE` can solve this. However, this is not 3NF; it's a really bad database design.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the replies.  I'm afraid that yes, this is poor database design, but I'm not a database whiz and I've been creating it more like a spreadsheet.  It's currently a pretty small DB, and moving data into its own table to ease organization may be possible.  It's also possible that moving forward this DB may be accessed with other programming, so python or PHP may provide an answer.  I'm sure the CASE clause could solve the problem, but don't think that's the route I want to go.  So much for a simple answer...  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tedious `CASE` clause can do what you need. For example (untested):

```
select
  concat(r1
    , case when r2 is null then '' else concat(',',r2) end
    , case when r3 is null then '' else concat(',',r3) end
    , case when r4 is null then '' else concat(',',r4) end
    , case when r5 is null then '' else concat(',',r5) end
  )
from (
  select
  case when wl1 = 1 then l1 when wl1 = 2 then l2 when wl1 = 3 then l3 when wl1 = 4 then l4 when wl1 = 5 then l5
       when wl1 = 6 then l6 when wl1 = 7 then l7 when wl1 = 8 then l8 when wl1 = 9 then l9 when wl1 = 10 then l10
       when wl1 = 11 then l11 when wl1 = 12 then l12 when wl1 = 13 then l13 when wl1 = 14 then l14 when wl1 = 15 then l15
  end as r1,
  case when wl2 = 1 then l1 when wl2 = 2 then l2 when wl2 = 3 then l3 when wl2 = 4 then l4 when wl2 = 5 then l5
       when wl2 = 6 then l6 when wl2 = 7 then l7 when wl2 = 8 then l8 when wl2 = 9 then l9 when wl2 = 10 then l10
       when wl2 = 11 then l11 when wl2 = 12 then l12 when wl2 = 13 then l13 when wl2 = 14 then l14 when wl2 = 15 then l15
  end as r2,
  case when wl3 = 1 then l1 when wl3 = 2 then l2 when wl3 = 3 then l3 when wl3 = 4 then l4 when wl3 = 5 then l5
       when wl3 = 6 then l6 when wl3 = 7 then l7 when wl3 = 8 then l8 when wl3 = 9 then l9 when wl3 = 10 then l10
       when wl3 = 11 then l11 when wl3 = 12 then l12 when wl3 = 13 then l13 when wl3 = 14 then l14 when wl3 = 15 then l15
  end as r3,
  case when wl4 = 1 then l1 when wl4 = 2 then l2 when wl4 = 3 then l3 when wl4 = 4 then l4 when wl4 = 5 then l5
       when wl4 = 6 then l6 when wl4 = 7 then l7 when wl4 = 8 then l8 when wl4 = 9 then l9 when wl4 = 10 then l10
       when wl4 = 11 then l11 when wl4 = 12 then l12 when wl4 = 13 then l13 when wl4 = 14 then l14 when wl4 = 15 then l15
  end as r4,
  case when wl5 = 1 then l1 when wl5 = 2 then l2 when wl5 = 3 then l3 when wl5 = 4 then l4 when wl5 = 5 then l5
       when wl5 = 6 then l6 when wl5 = 7 then l7 when wl5 = 8 then l8 when wl5 = 9 then l9 when wl5 = 10 then l10
       when wl5 = 11 then l11 when wl5 = 12 then l12 when wl5 = 13 then l13 when wl5 = 14 then l14 when wl5 = 15 then l15
  end as r5
  from t
) x
```

zzz...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up - despite asking for a SQL only solution, I don't think I'm going to go this route - I would likely be better served redesigning the as-yet small DB.  Cheers.

Comment: @SteveDuff Definitively a wise call.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this would be to correct the schema of your table. What you have right now is a PIVOT of the more appropriate schema. We can unpivot your table using a UNION query into the more appropriate schema, and then use a very simple SQL statement to perform the joins that you have written our in your question.

Consider a table:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (
  id int, 
  W1 int,
  W2 int,
  W3 int,
  W4 int,
  W5 int,
  L1 VARCHAR(30),
  L2 VARCHAR(30),
  L3 VARCHAR(30),
  L4 VARCHAR(30),
  L5 VARCHAR(30),
  L6 VARCHAR(30),
  L7 VARCHAR(30),
  L8 VARCHAR(30),
  L9 VARCHAR(30),
  L10 VARCHAR(30),
  L11 VARCHAR(30),
  L12 VARCHAR(30),
  L13 VARCHAR(30),
  L14 VARCHAR(30),
  L15 VARCHAR(30)
);
INSERT INTO yourtable (id, W1, W2, W3, L5, L7, L9) VALUES (1,5,7,9,'hey','hi','ho');
INSERT INTO yourtable (id, W1, W2, W3, L2, L3, L10) VALUES (2,2,3,10,'ha','he',NULL);
```

We can then unpivot using many unions and then query it much easier to get your answer. Note that this will only work as-is in Mysql 8+ but could be adapted for earlier versions to remove the CTE. Also note that this is not going to be fast.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id, 'W' as Entry, 1 as EntryKey, W1 as EntryVal FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'W', 2 , W2 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'W', 3 , W3 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'W', 4 , W4 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'W', 5 , W5 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 1, L1 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 2, L2 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 3, L3 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 4, L4 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 5, L5 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 6, L6 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 7, L7 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 8, L8 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 9, L9 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 10, L10 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 11, L11 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 12, L12 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 13, L13 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 14, L14 FROM yourtable
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'L' , 15, L15 FROM yourtable
)
SELECT dt1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(dt2.EntryVal)
FROM cte dt1
    INNER JOIN cte dt2
        ON dt1.EntryVal = dt2.EntryKey
        AND dt2.Entry = 'L'
WHERE dt1.Entry = 'W'
GROUP BY dt1.id;

+----+----------------------------+
| id | GROUP_CONCAT(dt2.EntryVal) |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | ho,hey,hi                  |
|  2 | he,ha                      |
+----+----------------------------+
```

[dbfiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8aqXEtxvgw6oTu8jKWZs1n/0)